# simple graph visualisation with coloring via paraview using vtk

Tags: vtk, paraview

I want to visualize some graph in paraview: a bunch of points with coordinates with a bunch of edges between them. I also want to color points and edges lines. I think this is not something hard to do with vtk format since i found that vtk format examples have almost something that i needed.

As i understand paraview uses point data to assign some scalar value to the point, and color lookup table to bind correspondence between scalar values and colors. But i barely can understand something from a description of lookup tables how to declare this.
I've started with some modifications on vtk example of cube:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Cube example
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 8 float
-1.0 -1.0 -1.0
1.0 -1.0 -1.0
1.0 1.0 -1.0
-1.0 1.0 -1.0
-1.0 -1.0 1.0
1.0 -1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0
-1.0 1.0 1.0
LINES 12 36
2 0 1
2 0 3
2 0 4
2 1 2
2 1 5
2 2 6
2 2 3
2 3 7
2 4 7
2 4 5
2 5 6
2 6 7

POINT_DATA 8
SCALARS sample_scalars float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE my_table
0.0
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
LOOKUP_TABLE my_table 8
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0
0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

0) I really don't understand how coloring was performed on the result visualization. ( http://i49.tinypic.com/igksqa.png ) . How does the numbers in this file corresponds to this coloring?

What i want to modify:

1) How can i implement visible points. In this vtk file points are just anchors for the lines and are not visible. I want to display them as well and be able to vary their size in paraview just like line width could be modified (Display -> Style -> Point size). Also i want those points to be colored as well.

2) Can i somehow be able to turn on\off come colors. Let's say i have 5 colors and i want to be able to display only nodes\edges with one of the color. If i understand correctly, this could be achieved using several scalar tables, where each scalar table has colors with opacity = 0 for those nodes\edges which i do not want to display.

3) Am i right that lines couldn't be referenced directly and they are colored only using the two points' data ?

Comment: Only a partial answer (#3), but you can color lines directly like this: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/GeometricObjects/ColoredLines

Answer (score 0):

[File Formats in VTK](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf)

Hi, in the link you will find the answers you want about the lookup tables(the examples made it more clear)

The best fit would be Unstructured Grid,  using differente cell types "vtk_vertex" and "vtk_line"

About the size, just apply a Glyph Filter to your data. You can set a scalar "Size" on your file, then you will be able to glyph each vertex by the size value you gave it.